# How to implement color picking on a cube in Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, cube, color-picker

I have already implemented a cube which can rotate by gestures in Android OpenGL ES. Now I want to implement that when I click somewhere on the cube, it can tell which face has been touched and make some response.

I searched the Internet and find color picking a good way, here are some tutorials: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php?color1

But I still find it difficult for me.

**How to assigned each face a different color?**

**How to read the pixel where the mouse was clicked from the back buffer?**

Can anyone show me some more details? Thanks a lot!

If you don't mind, leave me an email address and I can send you the work I have done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The first comment is that it's almost always faster to do this analytically — by casting a ray into the world. That comment aside...

You'd assign each face a different colour for picking just like for any other sort of rendering, whether by changing what you pass to `glColorPointer` (if using ES 1) or by switching to a single pixel, single coloured texture or by any other means. If you have lighting enabled, be sure to disable it.

You can use `glReadPixels` to read a colour back from a frame buffer. On a touch-screen device you probably want to grab, say, a 20x20 pixel area and pick whichever colour appears most often in it, or something like, that because fingers aren't very precise.

Comment: I still have some questions. In rendering color, why I need to disable the lighting? In color picking, you mentioned that finger picking are not very precise, does it mean in glReadPixels method I need to specify the picking range to 20*20 or even larger? Thanks! :-) @Tommy

Comment: If you leave the lighting on then it may change the colours you're rendering (eg because they're in the dark). The idea is that you read back, say, the colour (0, 0, 128) and instantly know that you've tapped object 128, but if dim lighting has reduced that to, say, (0, 0, 64) then you'll think a completely different object has been tapped. I'd definitely recommend you ask `glReadPixels` for a 20x20 area or larger (Apple always say 40px should be the minimum on their older 320x480 devices, but obviously your pixel densities may vary) and run through that.